# Copying and pasting cells with formulas in them

Tags: excel-formula

I just used a substitute formula to remove spaces from a set of cells, I did this in column D, using data from column C, when I try to move the new data from D to C it does a substitute formula for column B?

Does anyone know how to prevent this?

Comment: Copy D then right-click C and select Paste Special then select values only.

Comment: @DaveSexton that worked, thank you!!

Comment: If you want to copy the formula for use in other cells, it's possible that you could use absolute values, so when you move the formula, the references don't adjust with it. Say your formula (in cell B1) is `=Sum(A1:A10)`.  If you copy B1, and paste into D1, the formula will shift and the formula in D1 will be `=Sum(C1:C10)`, since you shifted the formula over.  If, in D1, you want to keep your A1 range, use this formula instead (in B1) - `=Sum($A1:$A10)`.  That way, when you move the formula around, the column referred to will still be A.

Answer (score 1):

You're pasting a formula, you need to paste values

[image]